# How to click and navigate on a new page programatically using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, element

I want to click on link on a page and navigate to a new page. I used following code for it :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname').click();
```

I used classname as it dont have id. document.getElementsByClassName('classname') works fine. But use of click() returns :

```
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function
```

Why I am getting this error? I read in couple of answers in stackoverflow that click() works fine. I am using this code in firebug console of firefox.

If click() won't work, what other options I have?

Comment: try `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, so you have to specify the index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click();
```

As a side note, programatically clicking an element doesn't run the native behavior, it runs the assigned click handlers for said element.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click();
```

> Returns a set of elements which have all the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)